# Strange occurrence retrieving all certificates on the machine using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using the following to retrieve all the certificates in the current user store:

```
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\
```

But what I need is to retrieve ALL certificates on the server, whether mine or under other users. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select thumbprint, subject, @{n="SignatureAlgorithm";e={$_.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName}}
```

directly in Powershell and it returned a long list of certificates, but when I try the same in powershell file:

```
$certs=Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select thumbprint, subject, @{n="SignatureAlgorithm";e={$_.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName}}
```

I get two records per each server and all are blank. For example if I do

```
foreach ($cert in $certs) {
    Write-Host $cert.Subject
}
```

I get blank. But if I do `Write-Host $certs.Count`, I get `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to provide `Get-ChildItem` with argument `Cert:\LocalMachine`, after that I think you have a typo - you assign results to `$certs` variable, but checking subject on `$cert`. This is working for me:

```
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse | select thumbprint, subject, @{n="SignatureAlgorithm";e={$_.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName}}
$certs.Subject
```

Comment: it is not a typo - after getting `$certs` I loop through each. As far as `Cert:\LocalMachine` goes, would I be able to retrieve also certs from all the users?

Comment: I doubt it. You can't do it through mmc

Comment: I need to automate it though